# Can I store .bib files in an external folder?

Tags: bibtex, citing, external-files

I would like to, having the following file structure

```
books/
--callen.bib
--munster.bib
source/
--thermodynamics.tex
```

where `callen.bib` and `munster.bib` store the `bibtex` information for the respective books, be able to cite them inside `thermodynamics.tex`. Is this possible?

Currently, I'm using

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}
```

where `references.bib` is a file that stores all `bibtex` information in the same folder as the `.tex` file, but this is not ideal for me.

I have found the solution for using multiple `.bib` files in the document, therefore editing the question.

(I'm quite unexperienced with LaTeX.)

Comment: `\bibliography{../books/callen,../books/munster}` should work: You can give multiple files in `\bibliography` and you can use relative file paths to find them. Usually the path needs to be relative to the working directory of BibTeX when you call it, which is usually the directory of your main `.tex` file.

Comment: @moewe How do I cite the book inside the text? `\cite{book-munster}` (if book-munster is the key in the `.bib` file) does not seem to work, nor does `\cite{munster}` (the name of the `.bib` file).

Comment: You use the exact key that you have in your `.bib` file. If that does not work, we need to know what exactly does not work. There should be warnings or error messages by both LaTeX and BibTeX (in the `.log` and `.blg` files, respectively) what do they say.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?